# Documentation specified in Open API does not export from AWS API Gateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I specify my AWS API Gateway APIs via the Open API spec. The specs contain a lot of documentation that I want client developers to use when integrating with the APIs. However, it seems the documentation we add to the Open API spec is not exported from API Gateway and thus is not available for consumption.

As already mentioned, I start off with an Open API spec in JSON.
I import this to API Gateway using the `CloudFormation AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource.

After this I deploy the API to a stage and, finally, export the documentation from this API+stage using the aws cli:

```
aws apigateway get-export \
    --parameters extensions='documentation' \
    --rest-api-id abc123 \
    --stage-name api \
    --export-type swagger \
    ./docs.json
```

This export appears to be missing a lot of crucial documentation properties such as `description` and `pattern`.

An example Open API parameter in my API:

```
{
    in: 'path',
    name: 'service',
    type: 'string',
    required: true,
    pattern: '^[-a-zA-Z0-9]+$',
    description: 'Name of the Service (document) to retrieve.'
}
```

When I export this with the aws-cli command above I get:

```
{
    "name" : "service",
    "in" : "path",
    "required" : true,
    "type" : "string"
}
```

The `description` and `pattern` properties have both been stripped from the documentation export which is bad since they really are the main part of the documentation for this parameter.

Also worth mentioning is that if I export the same API in the AWS Console (Swagger+API Gateway extensions) I get the same parameter definition as I did from the documentation export.

It might also be worth mentioning that the integrations are all based on Lambda proxy if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a Swagger template is imported, API Gateway splits the API definition and its documentation in two separate entities. This allows you to modify and deploy the two independently.

The export feature only exports whatever is deployed to a stage. Importing a Swagger template will cause both the API definition and the documentation parts to be imported. However, it looks like you only deployed the API definition. You have to explicitly publish the documentation before it becomes available in the export.

[image]

Like you pointed out, you can also use the CLI to publish a new version of the docs:

`aws apigateway create-documentation-version \
    --rest-api-id abc123 \
    --documentation-version 1 \
    --stage-name api`

Answer (score 0):

With a bit of help from the API Gateway team this has been resolved.

It appears a step was missing from my workflow.
After deploying the API, the documentation must be deployed:

```
aws apigateway create-documentation-version \
    --rest-api-id abc123 \
    --documentation-version 1 \
    --stage-name api
```

After doing this, the export command will yield the documentation instead of the API definition as it appears it did previously.